# nativeElement.querySelector not working in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, directive

I created a list.directive.ts to encapsulate some functionality and replicate it in multiple components. I want to use the directive in the component.ts.

I'm trying to capture the click in the button element without a click event in the html, that's why I'm using @HostListener but:

const specificElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#button'); doesn't seem to work

**[CODE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bklajw-9emvjq?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html,app%2Flist%2Flist.directive.ts,app%2Flist%2Flist.module.ts)**

**list.directive.ts**

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, HostListener} from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
    selector: '[ListDirective]'
})
export class ListDirective{
    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

    @HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])
    onClick(targetElement: HTMLButtonElement) {
       const specificElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#button');
  
       if (targetElement === specificElement) {
         console.log('Specific element clicked');
       }
       
    }

}
```

**list.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ListDirective } from './list.directive';
export { ListDirective };

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ListDirective
    ],
    exports: [
        ListDirective
    ]
})
export class ListModule {}
```

**Main.ts**

```
import {ListModule} from './app/list/list.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ListModule
  ],
  entryComponents: [TableBasicExample],
  declarations: [ListComponent],
  bootstrap: [TableBasicExample],
  providers: []
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Component where I want to use the list directive:

**component.ts**

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <button id="button" ListDirective type="button"> Open</button>
    <ul>
        <li>Sublist</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bklajw-3nwnv8. You need to go up a level before querying

Comment: If only want to "listen" the buton click you can use `@HostListener('click',['$event.target', '$event'])  onClick(targetElement: HTMLButtonElement, e: Event) {...}  }`, see that not listen the "document.click" else "click"

Answer (score 0):

Just check the classList of the specified class, instead of comparing elements, also you are checking for a child `#button` when the button id is located at the root element where the directive is located.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector: '[ListDirective]',
})
export class ListDirective {
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target', '$event'])
  onClick(targetElement: HTMLButtonElement, e: Event) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(
      this.elementRef,
      targetElement,
      targetElement.classList.contains('click-happens-here')
    );
    const specificElement =
      this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#button');

    if (targetElement === specificElement) {
      console.log('Specific element clicked');
    }
  }
}
```

html

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <button id="button" class="click-happens-here" ListDirective type="button">
      Open
    </button>
    <ul>
      <li>Sublist</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ujg7rv-ep5dur)

Answer (score 0):

If only want to "listen" the buton click you can use

```
 //, see that not listen the "document.click" else "click"
 @HostListener('click',['$event.target', '$event'])  
       onClick(targetElement: HTMLButtonElement, e: Event) {...}  
 }
```

If you want to listen any  click you can use some like

```
@HostListener('click',['$event.target', '$event']) 
  onClick(targetElement: HTMLButtonElement, e: Event) {
    console.log(targetElement.tagName,targetElement.innerHTML)
    switch(targetElement.tagName)
    {
       case 'BUTTON':
           ...
       case 'LI':
           ...
    }
  }
```

And apply the directive to the ul or to the li

```
<li ListDirective>
   ...
</li>
```

NOTE: Instead of HostListener you can also use rxjs fromEvent operator

```
import { fromEvent, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
@Directive({
  selector: '[ListDirective]',
})
export class ListDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  subscription: Subscription;
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = fromEvent(
      this.elementRef.nativeElement,
      'click'
    ).subscribe((_) => {
      console.log('click');
    });
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```